# Getting FileNotFoundException exception while writing data into S3 bucket

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

**While inserting into S3 bucket getting below error**

**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File s3n://data/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20230704174844_0087_m_000005_0 does not exist.**

```
df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("year")
             .mode(SaveMode.Append)
             .save("s3n://data/")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is referring the S3 file as `s3n://`, AFAIK the correct S3 URI is just `s3://`